# SSL verification problem when uploading a deb package using dput

Tags: python, ssl, debian, deb, dput

I'm building a .deb packages via `dh-make` utility. And I have to upload it to gitlab debain repository via `dput` utility.

After package has builded I run these commands:

```
cat <<EOF > dput.cf
[gitlab]
method = https
fqdn = <my login>:<my password>@gitlab.mydomain.com
incoming = /api/v4/projects/<project id>/packages/debian
EOF

dput --config=dput.cf --unchecked --no-upload-log gitlab <my package name>_1.0.1_amd64.changes
```

And I get this output log:

```
Uploading <my package name> using https to gitlab (host: <my login>:<my password>@gitlab.mydomain.com; directory: /api/v4/projects/<project id>/packages/debian)
running allowed-distribution: check whether a local profile permits uploads to the target distribution
running checksum: verify checksums before uploading
running suite-mismatch: check the target distribution for common errors
running gpg: check GnuPG signatures before the upload
Not checking GPG signature due to allow_unsigned_uploads being set.
Not writing upload log upon request
Uploading <my package name>_1.0.1.dsc
<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)>
```

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.
What should I do?

P.S. My personal gitlab ssl certificate (self-signed) added to trusted this way:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/share/ca-certificates

openssl s_client -showcerts -connect gitlab.mydomain.com:443 -servername gitlab.mydomain.com < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform PEM > /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/gitlab.mydomain.com.crt

update-ca-certificates
```

When I was testing it via http everything was good, but now it's only https left because of security reasons.

Many thanks for any hints.

I've tried to google it, about a half of answers tells me about python ssl config (via `certifi`), nothing helped me.

So I'm going around and around the `urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]`, but still no luck at all.

Comment: Uhh, why are you adding the servers certificate as a CA certificate? You need to trust the certificate of the CA that signed the servers certificate not the servers certificate itself.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have one, because as I mentioned before my server's certificate is self-signed

Comment: A self-signed certificate also needs a CA to sign it, its a separate matter that the CA is not a publically known one and its certificate and key are created by yourself only...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat A self-signed certificate is its own CA; the procedure that JFrol is following is broadly correct. It's probably a path issue of some sort.

Comment: @larsks Ah, I see, all the certificates I've generated so far I've created my own CA to sign them. JFrol run this `ls -l /etc/ssl/certs` and see if there's a symlink named like `gitlab.mydomain.com.pem` pointing to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/gitlab.mydomain.com.crt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend found a workaround to disable SSL verification for `dput`:

```
sed -i '24s/^/import ssl\nssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context\n/' /usr/bin/dput
```

Thanks everyone who tried to help.